# Hadoop forward scheduling

Tags: java, hadoop, scheduling, bigdata, decision-tree

In a google paper about implementing a decision tree for analysing Big Data, they mention something about forward scheduling map reduce jobs.

They say that if they currently have 2 jobs to run, they run the first job and the second job starts to setup. They have a thread for seeing when the first job is completed and when it does , they feed the input to the second job and start it. This saves them a lot of time because the algorithm they mention has iterative jobs.

I am wondering how can this be done on hadoop. Here is the citation of the paper. The forward scheduling is in paragraph 6.1

[Planet](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/36296.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use Oozie for that, you can do this in Java code directly.

I have written about how to realize iterative jobs in Hadoop:

http://codingwiththomas.blogspot.de/2011/04/controlling-hadoop-job-recursion.html

But notice that this is not very efficient, for iteration heavy algorithms you should better use [Apache Hama](http://hama.apache.org/).

Comment: Thanks thomas.I have seen your work before when i first started building this framework and i found some useful things.The thing is that i have complete it now and it works just fine, i only look for some optimizations.I found my self that hadoop is not very iterative and i saw your recommendations about hama, but i didn't want to mess up with new things since i was short on time. The thing that google build surely wasn't the most efficient but they managed to do it efficient with a lot of work in hadoop level.If hama and oozie are the only things that can help, then i ll look at them in time

Comment: No problem, hope that this iteration workflow will work for your mapreduce jobs.

Answer (score 2):

[Oozie](http://incubator.apache.org/oozie/) is what you are looking for. It's a bit immature as technology goes, but I believe it would handle the job flow functionality you describe. You can build dependency graphs and trigger execution on events.

Comment: thanks i will take a look at it but i am very short on time and i think i wont be able to use it, at least for now. I have already complete the framework and i now try to make it more efficient. Google did the same thing, they first complete it and then started a lot of optimizing, mostly on hadoop level and not in the algorithm it self. After all its google and i think they can do these kind of thins :P